# Financial fat tailed distribution - confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

I have financial data errors (from linear regression) that form a fat tailed distribution, I would like to calculate confidence intervals using that distribution, but I am not sure how to do that due to the fat tails?

Comment: How did you assess that the distribution of errors has fat-tails? And are the CIs that you are constructing for the model parameters, or for its fitted values? And we assume they're not *prediction* intervals. Lastly what is the $n$?

Comment: Questions about programming are off-topic, but hopefully the method (if applicable) can be laid out so you can work out the minutia on your own.

Comment: which fat tailed distribution?